# Kusto Query problem joining several calculated columns in the SAME table

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

I'm trying to figure out how to display data in Kusto but I'm running into some issues. I currently have these queries that work:

```
MyTable1
| where data contains "Books" and page contains "page1" and metricType contains "Count"
| summarize arg_max_value_books = arg_max(value, *) by userId, data
| extend data, userId, booksCount= arg_max_value_books
| project data, userId, booksCount
```

This returns, and the same for Tools and Cars

```
Data   | userId   | booksCount
----------------------------------------
Books | 12312   | 4
Books | 51341   | 3
Books | 12245   | 0

MyTable1
| where data contains "Tools" and the page contains "page1" and metricType contains "Count"
| summarize arg_max_value_tools = arg_max(value, *) by userId, data
| extend data, userId, toolsCount= arg_max_value_tools
| project data, userId, toolsCount

Data   | userId   | toolsCount
----------------------------------------
Tools| 12312    | 10
Tools| 51341    | 30
Tools| 12245    | 5


MyTable1
| where data contains "Cars" and page contains "page1" and metricType contains "Count"
| summarize arg_max_value_cars = arg_max(value, *) by userId, data
| extend data, userId, carsCount= arg_max_value_cars
| project data, userId, carsCount
```

The issue is that the "value" column is different whether the data is Tools, Cars or Books. I need a query to join all of these so that I can see something like:

```
 userId   | toolsCount | booksCount | carsCount
----------------------------------------------------------------
12312    | 10                | 4                     | 0
51341    | 30                | 3                     | 2
12245    | 5                  | 0                     | 12
```

I'm a bit confused about whether I should use merge, join, self-join, or something else, and most examples online talk about joining with another table, which is not what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pivot` plugin operator in the query instead of joins or merge. Below is the query:

```
MyTable1 
| where data contains "Books" and page contains "page1"
| extend Data = strcat(Data, 'Count')
| evaluate pivot(Data, max(Value))
```

Using `extend` operator, a new column named `Data` is created and the values in this new column are obtained by concatenating the existing values in the `Data` column with the string `Count` using `strcat()` function. The `Data` column is used as the pivot column and `max(Value)` function is used to aggregate the data for each combination of pivot column and other columns.

**Output:**

```
userId   | toolsCount | booksCount | carsCount
----------------------------------------------
12312      10                4           0
51341      30                3           2
12245      5                 0           12
```